# mvn archetype wont upload file without extension

Tags: maven

I can create mvn archetypes in my company's nexus. However, in the folder structures, I want to include some files that do not contain a file extension. These our proprietary files for a certain feature and I need them in the archetype.

How can I upload these non-extension files to my mvn archetype? Thank you

Comment: I just rant into this issue as well trying to get a 'Dockerfile' included in my archetype. Seems like such an obvious bug to fix.

Comment: The issue has been reported to Apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-548?jql=summary%20%20~%20%22extension%22%20AND%20summary%20~%20without%20and%20project%20%20%3D%20%22Maven%20Archetype%22%20